# Cannot send transactions to Flow emulator

Tags: onflow-cadence

I am trying to get the test code of the pinata-party working (https://medium.com/pinata/how-to-create-nfts-like-nba-top-shot-with-flow-and-ipfs-701296944bf).

It works fine to the point that I try and send a transaction:

flow transactions send --code "./transactions/MintPinataParty.cdc" --signer emulator-account

When I send that I get the error:

❌ Transaction Error
execution error code 1006: [Error Code: 1006] invalid proposal key: public key 0 on account f8d6e0586b0a20c7 does not have a valid signature: [Error Code: 1009] invalid envelope key: public key 0 on account f8d6e0586b0a20c7 does not have a valid signature: signature is not valid

Anyone have any idea where this is coming from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the issue was that the private key in my `flow.json` file did not match the private key being used when starting the emulator. I was running the emulator via the `Run Emulator` command in VS Code. The private key being used for the emulator was in the command output.

Comment: could you elaborate how did you get the private key while starting the emulator to match with the private key in `flow.json`? I tried running the command you provided `Run Emulator` but it is giving me error.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the exact same error, fixed by updating to the latest flow-cli version. I was on 0.17.0, but was running the emulator in Docker which was 0.21.0.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else that comes across this issue, I had two flow.json files in my project. One in the current folder that i was running the terminal commands from, and another a couple folders above. I had to delete the one above so that there was only one flow.json in the entire project.